# Regex to find length in description

Tags: regex, coldfusion

```
<cfset RegexToFindLength = "Length:.*?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(""|")"/>

<cfset Description = "blah blah blah 2.5"""/>

<cfset size = #reMatch(RegexToFindLength, Description)# />

<cfdump var="#size#">
```

Error Message: ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
)

looking to extract Length: 2.5" from the products description.

I have tested the above regex expression in regexpal and it works. But when i try using it in a cfm page, i get errors.

Can someone explain to me how this would be setup in CF?

Comment: What are the errors, and what is the code generating the error? There's no way to help you without knowing what you did, and what the result was.

Comment: You may probably may have escape your characters properly when implementing in coldfusion. For e.g., escape the quotes. Also you may want to consider making your * quantifier non-greedy for whitespace like this: `Length:.*?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*?(""|")`. Show us [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
.  So I am thinking that it has to do with escaping. I would need to escape each special character? Or can I convert them to ascii codes? Seems like overkill.

Comment: @FrankD'Elia please edit your original question to include the ColdFusion code and the error message.

Comment: Kash - changing `\s*` to `\s*?` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here.

1) You don't escape your double quotes, so you end up closing your regex string and confusing it.

Personally, when I have to use double quotes in a string, I tend to use single quotes to define the string if I can.

> ```
> <cfset RegexToFindLength = 'Length:.*?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(""|")'/>
> ```

2) Your `Description` variable doesn't have the string you're searching for, so there will be no match. I changed this to the following to make it work (note the single quotes for defining the string):

> ```
> <cfset Description = 'Length:.:2.5""'/>
> ```

3) (maybe not an issue) `Size` is not being set to a number. `rematch` returns an array of strings. You'll want to check the length of the string inside the array positions or check the length of the array itself - I don't know what exactly it is that you want to do.

Comment: ok guys thanks for the help, my mistake the word length was in my original code, when I typed it here i forgot to include it here. The problem was the double quotes. I also surrounded each statement with single quotes. That fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: btw, this regex can be more efficient (with no behaviour change) by changing it to this: `Length:\D*\d*\.?\d+\s*"{1,2}` - specifically the `\D*` instead of `.*?` ensures it doesn't look for the `\d` before it needs to.